# Xamarin Forms Multiple Custom Controls Per Page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have some custom renderers and Controls that works. But how can I place multiple custom controls in one Xamarin Forms xaml page.?

Thanks

Comment: You just need to make sure you load the namespace where those controls are and then reference them in the XAML.  So say you load them as xmlns:Local=<clr-namespace:CustomControls;assembly=CustomControls>  then you access them like so, <local:MyCustomControl  />.  Then as stated in an answer below you simply put them in the layout that you wish to set.  See examples here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/entry/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap everything in whatever normal Layouts you want, e.g. a StackLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the namespace of your custom controls in the header of the xaml page then reference them within the layout. For example the custom controls in the below code are in the PCL under the folder CustomControls.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"    
             xmlns:customcontrols="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace.CustomControls;assembly=MyNameSpace"
             x:Class="MyNameSpace.Views.Page_One"
             Title="Page One">

<StackLayout x:Name="stackContent" VerticalOptions="Fill"HorizontalOptions="Fill">

<customcontrols:MY_Entry x:Name="entry1" ></customcontrols:MY_Entry>

<customcontrols:MY_Label x:Name="label1" ></customcontrols:MY_Label>

</Stacklayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: What if i have two custom controls and both are in different namespaces?

Comment: Add both in the xmlns header?